# How to place two "items" next to each other in the center

Tags: positioning

I want to place the Karnaughquatre and the array next to each other and centered. How can I achieve that?

```
\begin{Karnaughquatre}
    \contingut{1, 0, 0, 1}
\end{Karnaughquatre}

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{C C|C}
    $A$ & $B$ & $F$\\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
```

Edit 1:
Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25 in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25 in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6 in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5 in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5 in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.75 in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0 in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1 in}

%
% ADD PACKAGES here:
%

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}

%
% The following commands set up the lecnum (lecture number)
% counter and make various numbering schemes work relative
% to the lecture number.
%
\newcounter{lecnum}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecnum.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thelecnum.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecnum.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thelecnum.\arabic{table}}

%
% The following macro is used to generate the header.
%
    \newcommand{\lecture}[4]{
    \pagestyle{myheadings}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
   \framebox{
      \vbox{\vspace{2mm}
    \hbox to 6.28in { {\bf Logic Design
    \hfill Fall 2017} }
       \vspace{4mm}
       \hbox to 6.28in { {\Large \hfill Lecture #1: #2  \hfill} }
       \vspace{2mm}
       \hbox to 6.28in { {\it Lecturer: #3 \hfill Scribes: #4} }
      \vspace{2mm}}
   }
   \end{center}
   \markboth{Lecture #1: #2}{Lecture #1: #2}

  {\bf Note}: {\it LaTeX notes for Logic Design.}

   {\bf Disclaimer}: {\it These notes have not been subjected to the
   usual scrutiny reserved for formal publications.  They may be distributed
   outside this class only with the permission of the Instructor.}
   \vspace*{4mm}
}

\newcommand\E{\mathbb{E}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

%Empty Karnaugh map 2x2
\newenvironment{Karnaughquatre}%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (2,2);
\draw (0,2) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west] {b} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east] {a} ++(135:1);
%
\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
        column sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        row sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        every node/.style={minimum size=0.3mm},
        anchor=2.center,
        ampersand replacement=\&] at (0.5,0.5)
{
          \& |(c00)| 0          \& |(c01)| 1  \\
|(r00)| 0 \& |(0)|  \phantom{0} \& |(1)|  \phantom{0} \\
|(r01)| 1 \& |(2)|  \phantom{0} \& |(3)|  \phantom{0} \\
};
}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Defines 8 or 16 values (0,1,X)
\newcommand{\contingut}[1]{%
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0]  in {#1}
     \path (\xi) node {\x};
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>$c<$}

\begin{document}
%FILL IN THE RIGHT INFO.
%\lecture{**LECTURE-NUMBER**}{**DATE**}{**LECTURER**}{**SCRIBE**}
\lecture{5}{November 08}{Paschalis Antonis}{Platon Kiorpelidis}
%\footnotetext{These notes are partially based on those of Nigel Mansell.}

% **** YOUR NOTES GO HERE:

% Some general latex examples and examples making use of the
% macros follow.  
%**** IN GENERAL, BE BRIEF. LONG SCRIBE NOTES, NO MATTER HOW WELL WRITTEN,
%**** ARE NEVER READ BY ANYBODY.

\section{K-map of 2 variables}

\vspace{2pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{Karnaughquatre}
    \contingut{1, 0, 0, 1}
\end{Karnaughquatre}

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{C C|C}
    $A$ & $B$ & $F$\\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Ideally it should compile  unless, of course, that is what you are asking about.

Comment: I added the MWE in my question. Take a look at it and let me know if there is a problem with it.

Comment: A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) should have *smallest* amount of code necessary that compiles and demonstrates your problem. Your MWE seems to contain a lot of unnecessary material. The easier you make it for people to help you the more likely that some one will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `array` inside `$` delimiters (instead of `displaymath`) to make it an inline box that can be placed on the same line with other stuff.

Then, I used `stackengine` to lay the `Karnaughquatre` on the baseline, and  used `[b]` alignment on the `array` to do likewise.  A `\qquad` was placed between them for separation.

The vertical shift of the `Karnaughquatre` can be further adjusted with the optional argument to `\abovebaseline`, currently set to `0pt`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25 in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25 in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6 in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5 in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5 in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.75 in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0 in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1 in}

%
% ADD PACKAGES here:
%

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}

%
% The following commands set up the lecnum (lecture number)
% counter and make various numbering schemes work relative
% to the lecture number.
%
\newcounter{lecnum}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecnum.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thelecnum.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecnum.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thelecnum.\arabic{table}}

%
% The following macro is used to generate the header.
%
    \newcommand{\lecture}[4]{
    \pagestyle{myheadings}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
   \framebox{
      \vbox{\vspace{2mm}
    \hbox to 6.28in { {\bf Logic Design
    \hfill Fall 2017} }
       \vspace{4mm}
       \hbox to 6.28in { {\Large \hfill Lecture #1: #2  \hfill} }
       \vspace{2mm}
       \hbox to 6.28in { {\it Lecturer: #3 \hfill Scribes: #4} }
      \vspace{2mm}}
   }
   \end{center}
   \markboth{Lecture #1: #2}{Lecture #1: #2}

  {\bf Note}: {\it LaTeX notes for Logic Design.}

   {\bf Disclaimer}: {\it These notes have not been subjected to the
   usual scrutiny reserved for formal publications.  They may be distributed
   outside this class only with the permission of the Instructor.}
   \vspace*{4mm}
}

\newcommand\E{\mathbb{E}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

%Empty Karnaugh map 2x2
\newenvironment{Karnaughquatre}%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (2,2);
\draw (0,2) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west] {b} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east] {a} ++(135:1);
%
\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
        column sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        row sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        every node/.style={minimum size=0.3mm},
        anchor=2.center,
        ampersand replacement=\&] at (0.5,0.5)
{
          \& |(c00)| 0          \& |(c01)| 1  \\
|(r00)| 0 \& |(0)|  \phantom{0} \& |(1)|  \phantom{0} \\
|(r01)| 1 \& |(2)|  \phantom{0} \& |(3)|  \phantom{0} \\
};
}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Defines 8 or 16 values (0,1,X)
\newcommand{\contingut}[1]{%
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0]  in {#1}
     \path (\xi) node {\x};
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>$c<$}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
%FILL IN THE RIGHT INFO.
%\lecture{**LECTURE-NUMBER**}{**DATE**}{**LECTURER**}{**SCRIBE**}
\lecture{5}{November 08}{Paschalis Antonis}{Platon Kiorpelidis}
%\footnotetext{These notes are partially based on those of Nigel Mansell.}

% **** YOUR NOTES GO HERE:

% Some general latex examples and examples making use of the
% macros follow.  
%**** IN GENERAL, BE BRIEF. LONG SCRIBE NOTES, NO MATTER HOW WELL WRITTEN,
%**** ARE NEVER READ BY ANYBODY.

\section{K-map of 2 variables}

\vspace{2pt}
\begin{center}
\abovebaseline[0pt]{%
\begin{Karnaughquatre}
    \contingut{1, 0, 0, 1}
\end{Karnaughquatre}}
\qquad
$
\begin{array}[b]{C C|C}
    $A$ & $B$ & $F$\\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]